# VS2015 showing objects as null that are not null

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm not sure if it's just refusing to load the debug symbols for this one project, or what the issue might be, as I've not seen this before.

The object it shows as being `null`, I can pass this allegedly null object to another section of the solution (i.e. another project), and magically, it's no longer null.

It is only inside 1 project in the solution that it says a bunch of objects are null.

For example, it says everything is:

`DTL = 'DTL' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`

Even if I put an if block that says

```
if(DTL != null) {
    //do some work
}
```

It will enter this if block, while simultaneously claiming that DTL is null.

Edit:

Wow... I opened the solution in VS2013 and this doesn't happen

Only in VS2015.

Edit 2:

I just noticed there is a Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 available. This must have released in the last few days.

I will update VS2015 and see if this issue persists.

Comment: Is this C#?   You probably should add a language tag.  Are you debugging a Debug build or a Release build?  Does the output window have lines indicating whether symbols were found for the loaded modules?

Comment: Yes it claims to have loaded the debug modules for that project

Comment: And is it a Debug build or a Release build?

Comment: It's a debug build